# Is there a proper Stack Exchange site for language specific feature requests?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, scope, site-recommendation

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256199/syntax-alternatives-to-casting-of-dynamic-objects), which generated some discussion and led me to an alternative solution, but I think the underlying feature would make a good addition to a future version of the language.

Is there a place where requests for features (not Stack Overflow features, but product-specific features) where they can be commented and voted on?

Comment: You mean products that are not Stack Exchange products? Things like C#, Java, Perl etc?

Comment: And please explain who exactly is supposed to act on the feature requests?

Comment: @Joe: I've edited your question title to reflect the distinction that SE is a Q&A network rather than a free form discussion forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 99.999%<sup>*</sup> of these cases, StackOverflow is not going to be the proper place to solicit feature requests. We can't answer a feature request! Well, I can't answer a request to add syntax to the C# compiler and neither can all but a minuscule number of folks on the network.

In the *general case* of your question, sites like UserVoice exist to handle these sorts of problems.

In the *specific case*, you have to go to the horse's mouth to make these suggestions. For example, [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) may be a good place for MS product suggestions or filing a [Java Specification Requests (JSRs)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview) to handle Java ideas.

Basically, StackOverflow was not built to handle requests for features for a community to vote on.

<sub>*I'm sure you could concoct a legitimate question which ended up being a feature request of sorts, but that will not be common.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there's a good place for such things on stackexchange. Possibly on programmers.se, but I would leave that to their community.

This is not a specific question that can have a specific answer.

Comment: Not appropriate on Programmers either, since feature requests for various products aren't Q&A.